# Output Spring-WS Generated WSDL Location

Tags: spring-ws

This seems like a simple question to me:

I have a project where I automatically generate a Spring-WS WSDL, something like this:

```
<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="service"                                                           
    portTypeName="Service"                                                         
    locationUri="/Service/"                                                       
    targetNamespace="http://location.com/Service/schemas/Mos">                               
        <sws:xsd location="classpath:/META-INF/Service.xsd"/>                                                  
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

Is there a way, on application context startup, to output the generated address of the wsdl, including context, location, etc? This would be handy if our integration tests start to fail, we can see if the location of the WSDL has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can find the WSDL at `http://yourHost/yourServletContext/beanId.wsdl`. In your case, beanId is 'service'.

Check out [3.7. Publishing the WSDL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-publishing-wsdl) in the Spring-WS documentation for more information about this subject.

If you plan to expose your XSD's as well, the `beanId.xsd` (or, in my case the method name in the `@Configuration` class) format will be used. For instance:

```
private ClassPathResource exampleXsdResource = new ClassPathResource("example.xsd");

@Bean public SimpleXsdSchema example() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(exampleXsdResource);
}
```

This exposes an XSD at `http://yourHost/yourServletContext/example.xsd`.

Comment: The question hasn't been answered.

Comment: Wow, after three years. You might be right, but on the other hand my answer provides the means of solving the problem (for instance) within your @Configuration class which logs the generated URL to a logger.